# DB2 StatementPool configuration issue

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement

I'm trying to activate the statementPool with the db2 jdbc driver, and i m having trouble doing so.
I've tried different techniques mentionned here : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.java%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_c0052041.htm

Here is the java code :

```
csUrl += ":maxStatements=1000;";
System.err.println("Connecting to csUrl : " + csUrl);

DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource();
//DB2SimpleDataSource ds = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
//ds = new DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource();
ds.setServerName("edited");
ds.setPortNumber(edited);
ds.setDatabaseName("edited");
ds.setCurrentSchema("edited");
ds.setMaxStatements(1000);
ds.setDriverType(4);
Connection connection = ds.getPooledConnection(csUser, csPassword).getConnection();
//Connection connection = ds.getConnection(csUser, csPassword);
//Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(csUrl);
//Connection connection = m_driver.connect(csUrl, propertiesUserPassword);
boolean pooling = connection.getMetaData().supportsStatementPooling();
if (pooling) {
System.err.println(">>> Pooling is ON!");
} else {
System.err.println(">>> Pooling is OFF! <<<");
}
```

All techniques fail according to :  `connection.getMetaData().supportsStatementPooling()` and statementPooling is always deactivated.

I'm running DB2 Express /Linux :
 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.1.2
with the matching jdbc driver.

Same code with a different db2 backend (db2 10 zOs) gives the same result, so i guess it s not an Express issue.
Client code is running on windows.

We have a in-house statement cache, but i wanted to play around with DB2's especially since it can apparently share the pool in between logical connections provided thru a PooledDataSource

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe it is actually pooling but incorrectly reporting pooling via the getMetaData().supportsStatementPooling() API.  Why don't you attach a listener via connection.addStatementEventListener(StatementEventListener listener) and see if you are getting events.  If your listener does get called with PreparedStatement objects, then it is pooling.

Comment: What the metadata reports doesn't always conform with the reality of the connection pool implementation. Also, I hope you are aware that a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation in general is not (or shouldn't be) a connection pool, but is to be **used by** a connection pool (eg as provided by an application server).

Comment: Well, documentation in the link i gave explicitly mentions :    In a Java program, you can test whether the internal statement cache is enabled by issuing the DatabaseMetaData.supportsStatementPooling method. The method returns true if the internal statement cache is enabled.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks a lot, how come i did not know that? You cant see this is testing code?

Comment: @fork1 Re `ConnectionPoolDataSource`: it is in the JDBC spec, see chapter 11 of the JDBC 4.1 spec, or the [javax.sql package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html); re metadata: the semantics of this specific metadata isn't really clear; some interpret it as 'does this database allow the statement to be pooled' (ie: does it make sense to try to pool a statement), while others interpret it as 'are statements pooled'. To me the first makes more sense (esp because of third party connection/statement pools)

Comment: I am NOT interested in JDBC standard interfaces. I m interested in DB2 specifics. So DB2 documentation applies. Not jdbc specs.  DB2 doc. says supportsStatementPooling() will return true if statement pooling is enabled.